# segmentation fault (core dumped) without errors or warnings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I made coded this header and there were no errors no warnings everything seemed great, but then I tried to run it and it said:

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I looked trough the code several times tried <string.h> and <malloc.h> (maybe I had a faulty implementation of them idk), but none of it seemed to work
main:

```
#include "SimpleScreen.h"

int main(){
    ScreenHeight = 10;
    ScreenWidth = 40;

    screen("write",5,7,12,0);
    screen("print",0,0,0,0);
}
```

SimpleScreen.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PrintColor.h"
#include "AdMath.h"

char background_occupacy[101] = {' ','@','@','@','@','@','@','W','W','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','B','Q','G','P','N','N','&','O','D','g','S','E','m','w','A','8','Z','K','H','6','9','X','C','p','b','q','5','U','2','O','e','3','a','V','V','F','4','h','k','o','s','y','u','n','n','c','T','z','z','7','J','x','L','L','v','?','?','=','f','t','t','j',')','(','(','r','r','i','^','/','*','_',';',';',':','-',',','.','.',' ',' ',' ',' '};

int ScreenHeight = 20;
int ScreenWidth = 35;

void screen(char mode[5],int x, int y, int color, int AssignToType){
  //copy vaules of adresses

  char write[5] = {"write"};
  char print[5] = {"print"};

  int ScreenSpace[ScreenHeight][ScreenWidth][3];//[][][3] 0 ^= foreground_color, 1 ^= background_color, 2 ^= (background)occupacy

  if(*mode = *write){
    ScreenSpace[x][y][AssignToType] = color;

  }

  if(*mode = *print){
    for(int i = 0; i < ScreenHeight; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < ScreenWidth; j++){
        HighIntensity = (IsEven(ScreenSpace[i][j][0] == 1));

        text_color(((ScreenSpace[i][j][0]+1) / 2) -1);

        background_color((((ScreenSpace[i][j][1]+1) / 2) -1)*!(ScreenSpace[i][j][2] == 0)  +  (((ScreenSpace[i][j][0]+1) / 2) -1)*(ScreenSpace[i][j][2] == 0));

        printf("%c%c",background_occupacy[ScreenSpace[i][j][2]],background_occupacy[ScreenSpace[i][j][2]]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: a suggestion: 1) do not put code nor variable declarations into a header file

Comment: Local arrays in C aren't initialized.  So if `mode` is `"print"` the contents of `ScreenSpace[x][y][AssignToType]` are uninitialized garbage and printing it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: then how to I make the array a global array? After all the array is supposed to have a flexible size

Comment: You can't have both; global objects must have constant size.  So depending on what lifetime it should have, either keep it local to `screen` or have a global pointer which points to dynamically allocated memory, but either way you have to write a loop or use `memset` to initialize it manually.

Comment: You can't change your question completely after receiving an answer to it! Rolling it back. If you have another question - ask it a separate one.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statements `if(*mode = *write){` and `if(*mode = *print){` are writing to string literals passed as the argument. Modifying string literals is prohibited.

If you want to check only the first characters, you should use `==` operator (two equal signs, not one) like `if(*mode == *write){` and `if(*mode == *print){`.

If you want to check if the whole strings matches, you should

- Stop explicitly specifying the element size not to prevent it from putting the terminating null-character.
- Use [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare strings.

In other words, the lines

```
char write[5] = {"write"};
char print[5] = {"print"};
```

should be

```
char write[] = "write";
char print[] = "print";
```

and the lines

```
if(*mode = *write){
if(*mode = *print){
```

should be

```
if(strcmp(mode, write) == 0){
if(strcmp(mode, print) == 0){
```

Also

```
#include <string.h>
```

should be added to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: that didn't solve the issue: I tried something similar already(I changed the mode to int) and it didn't work and now I've tried your idea as well without success

Comment: @Maximilian There are many things that can cause segfault. This one is definitely one of these. Since you haven't posted [mcve] you can't expects people to guess which other issues you might be having in your code

Comment: the issues seems to be the ScreenSpace array itself. The value it has is 1691648 wherever nothing has been written to